# How to make a WX Python For Loop for updating a series of text boxes

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I was asked to make a Subnet Scanner App for a summer class. The app is complete but its ugly as sin because the code is extremely lengthy.

It is lengthy because the app requirements called for a gui with 8 ip addresses on them and whether or not there had been a return at that IP.

Since it required a GUI, I created a series of static text fields to represent the individual IPs it was scanning.

That app has a scanner button and once that button is pressed and the scan resolves, it goes to update the board with the appropriate values.

To make it easier, I set up a global placeholder value to just increment by 8 each time I needed to see a new set.

So heres what I'd like to do

I'd like to make a for loop that updates the static text of each of the eight fields without having to write each one out individually.

What I have that works is below:

```
self.XValue0.SetLabel(str(placeholder))
self.XValue1.SetLabel(str(placeholder1))
self.XValue2.SetLabel(str(placeholder2))
self.XValue3.SetLabel(str(placeholder3))
self.XValue4.SetLabel(str(placeholder4))
self.XValue5.SetLabel(str(placeholder5))
self.XValue6.SetLabel(str(placeholder6))
self.XValue7.SetLabel(str(placeholder7))
```

XValue is in reference to 192.168.1.X where X is the value being changed since the first part of the Subnet stays the same anyway.

The placeholder with a number is in reference to a global value that adds the number (1-7) to the placeholder to populate the field.

For instance, if the GUI starts at 192.168.1.0, it would populate down to 192.168.1.7 and display the yes or no for all positions in that range.

What I would like to do is something more similar to this:

```
for x in range(0,7):

 PlaceholderValue = str(placeholder + x)
 XValue = 'XValue' + PlaceholderValue
 self.XValue.setLabel(PlaceholderValue)
```

However, when I do that, the console gives me an error saying it can't find "XValue".

My question is this. Is there a way to make that for loop work the way I want it to, or is it by necessity the longer code based on how I wrote it. Thanks all. Sorry for the long post, its my first question after lurking for ages. Please let me know if you all need anymore info.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your static text objects, save the references in a list as well as (or instead of) the XValue attributes.

```
self.XValues = []
for x in range(8):
    self.XValues.append(wx.StaticText(...))
```

then it makes it much easier to loop over and update later

```
for i, xvalue in enumerate(self.XValues):
    xvalue.SetLabel(placeholder + i)
```

You can still access the labels individually too, for instance to access `XValue4` you had before, you can do `self.XValues[4]`.

Also, you could have done it like you tried, except you need to use `getattr` to dynamically get attributes of objects, but you're better off storing the labels in a list.

```
for x in range(8):

    PlaceholderValue = str(placeholder + x)
    XValue = 'XValue' + PlaceholderValue
    getattr(self, XValue).setLabel(PlaceholderValue)
```